# Authenticate and use Google Cloud Speech API

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-speech

I am trying to make a PHP application using which I can send a .flac file to the google speech service and get text in return.

Following the [official guide](https://github.com/googlecloudplatform/google-cloud-php#google-cloud-speech-alpha)

This is the authentication code:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Google\Cloud\Core\ServiceBuilder;

// Authenticate using keyfile data
$cloud = new ServiceBuilder([
    'keyFile' => json_decode(file_get_contents('b.json'), true)
]);
```

Then this is the speech code:

```
use Google\Cloud\Speech\SpeechClient;
$speech = new SpeechClient([
    'languageCode' => 'en-US'
]);

// Recognize the speech in an audio file.
$results = $speech->recognize(
    fopen(__DIR__ . '/audio_sample.flac', 'r')
);

foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo $result->topAlternative()['transcript'] . "\n";
}
```

Of course the $cloud variable is never used. Where should it go?

I ran it nonetheless got

> Uncaught exception 'Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException'
>   with message '{ "error": { "code": 401, "message": "Request had
>   invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token,
>   login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See
>   https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
>   "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED" } }

I just want to make a simple query. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you created a key file?

Comment: @rtfm: Yes, b.json is a valid key file. Had followed the following link to create it: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
use Google\Cloud\Speech\SpeechClient;
$speech = new SpeechClient([
    'languageCode' => 'en-US',
    'keyFile' => json_decode(file_get_contents('b.json'), true)
]);

// Recognize the speech in an audio file.
$results = $speech->recognize(
    fopen(__DIR__ . '/audio_sample.flac', 'r')
);

foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo $result->topAlternative()['transcript'] . "\n";
}
```

You bring up a good point regarding the documentation. Changes over the last few months have caused this somewhat confusing situation, and it deserves another look to clarify things. I've created an [issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-php/issues/831) to resolve this.

`ServiceBuilder` is a class which provides factories allowing you to configure Google Cloud PHP once and create different clients (such as Speech or Datastore) which inherit that configuration. All the options on `ServiceBuilder::__construct()` are also available in the clients themselves, such as `SpeechClient`, with a couple of exceptions.

If you want to use the ServiceBuilder, you could do something like this:

```
use Google\Cloud\Core\ServiceBuilder;

$cloud = new ServiceBuilder([
    'keyFile' => json_decode(file_get_contents('b.json'), true)
]);

$speech = $cloud->speech([
    'languageCode' => 'en-us'
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can call **putenv** before before working with api:

```
/** Setting Up Authentication. */
$key_path = '/full/path/to/key-file.json';
putenv( 'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=' . $key_path );
```